# Time series multiple plot for different group in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a large data frame of several variables (around 50)  with first column as `date` and second column `id`.

My data roughly look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("01-04-2001 00:00","01-04-2001 00:00","01-04-2001 00:00",
                      "01-05-2001 00:00","01-05-2001 00:00","01-05-2001 00:00",
                      "01-06-2001 00:00","01-06-2001 00:00","01-06-2001 00:00",
                      "01-07-2001 00:00","01-07-2001 00:00","01-07-2001 00:00"), 
             id = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), 
             b = c(2,2.5,3,3.2,4,4.6,5,5.6,8,8.9,10,10.6))
```

I want time series plots for all three ids separately in same graph of variables, `a` and `b` in different graphs.

I tried `ggplot`  but it didn't work. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** After reading the comments, maybe you should try something like this:

```
library(tidyr)
df2 <- gather(df, variable, value, -date, -id)
vars <- unique(df2$variable)

library(ggplot2)
for (i in 1:length(vars)) {
  ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data = subset(df2, variable == vars[[i]]), 
              aes(date, value, group = id, color = factor(id))) +
    ylab(as.character(vars[[i]])) +
    ggsave(file = paste0(vars[[i]], ".png"))
}
```

This should save a PNG for each variable in your dataframe (and will *change y label of every plot to variable name*, as per your request)

Comment: @ Steven thanks for helping me but .I have more than 50 variables. So its not possible to plot like this. So i want that it plot one after another so that i can save graph for each variable separately

Comment: I want to change y label of every plot to variable name by ylab(colnames(df[i]) but its nor working. I am getting this error: "Error in +ylab(colnames(data)[i]) : invalid argument to unary operator". may you please me something

Comment: @Rajan, might be better to access the vars variable since it's part of the for loop. Try `ylab(as.character(vars[[i]]))`

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this?

```
library(reshape)
library(lattice)

df2 <- melt(df, id.vars = c("date", "id"), measure.vars = c("a", "b"))

xyplot(value ~ date | variable, group = id, df2, t='l')
```

[image]

**Addendum**

```
# The following is from a comment by jbaums. 
# It will create a single plot/file for each variable of df2
png('plots%02d.png')
xyplot(value ~ date | variable, group = id, df2, t='l', layout=c(1, 1), 
       scales=list(alternating=FALSE, tck=1:0))
dev.off()
```

You can also add `relation='free'` to `scales` so that y-axis limits are calculated separately for each plot.

Comment: Probs should `as.Date` first, in case the true dataset has missing dates.

Comment: yeah, sort of this,  but I want to plot it in different windows as I have more than 50 variables. Also want to put legend for different colors.

Comment: @Rajan Please clarify.

Comment: @jbaums Yes, it should.

Comment: Since I have more than 50 variables and they have different maximum and minimum value. I want them as separate so that i can save each variable plot as separate png file

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it in ggplot, using the tidyr package to get it in the right format:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(date = c("01-04-2001 00:00","01-04-2001 00:00","01-04-2001 00:00",
                      "01-05-2001 00:00","01-05-2001 00:00","01-05-2001 00:00",
                      "01-06-2001 00:00","01-06-2001 00:00","01-06-2001 00:00",
                      "01-07-2001 00:00","01-07-2001 00:00","01-07-2001 00:00"), 
             id = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), 
             b = c(2,2.5,3,3.2,4,4.6,5,5.6,8,8.9,10,10.6))
```

Then using dplyr's group_by and do functions, we can save multiple plots.

```
df %>%
  gather(variable, value, -date, -id) %>%
  mutate(id = factor(id)) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  do(
    qplot(data = ., x = date, y = value, geom = "line", group = id, color = id, main = paste("variable =", .$variable)) +
          ggsave(filename = paste0(.$variable, ".png")
             )
    )
```

Comment: @MichaelT thanks for helping me but .I have more than 50 variables. So its not possible to plot like this. So i want that it plot one after another so that i can save graph for each variable separately

Comment: Clever use of  `do()` here. +1

Comment: You should use `paste0()` or `paste(sep = "")` so there is no space in filename.